# local parameter z=-x/y of p-adic expansion

Tags: elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory

My curve is given by `ellinit([0,0,0,-3267,45630])` and point `P=[-21,324]`. Local parameter (`z=-x/y`) of point `24P = 2*3+3^2+2*3^3 +O(3^5)`. My concern is how am I to find the local parameter of point `24kP` (with the term k appearing in the p-adic expansion). Is there a certain formula that i can use?

Comment: I wonder whether you m ight expand your question somewhat. Your curve seems to be $Y^2=X^3-3267X+45630$, yes? So this curve has a cusp modulo $3$? And you are working $3$-adically? And you have a $\Bbb Q$-point $P=(-21,324)$? And you have taken the $24-$-fold multiple, which I would have written $[24](P)$? Am I right? By this point, I have gone perhaps too far out on the limb. As I say, could you expand?

Comment: @Lubin Thank you for your reply. And you are right about everything you have wrote. I am using software PARI, so I copy paste the command here. I just want to know how to find the point 24kP where k is any positive integer, so that I can find the 3-adic expansion of 24kP where P=[-21,324].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, let’s call $Q=[24](P)$. I’m assuming that your evaluation of the local coordinate of $Q$ is correct, let’s denote it $\xi\in\Bbb Z_3$. The best way I know of to calculate $[k](Q)$ is to use the logarithm and exponential of the formal group of your curve. There are other ways, of course. Because your curve has additive reduction and is defined over $\Bbb Q_3$, the logarithm $L(x)$ will be a $\Bbb Z_3$-series (no denominators!), which is pleasant, ’cause it means that the exponential series $E(x)$ also is in $\Bbb Z_3[[x]]$, and so has good convergence properties. Just take $\xi$, calculate $L(\xi)$, multiply by $k$, and substitute this value into $E(x)$. It works because the logarithm is a homomorphism into the additive formal group, where the $[k]$-map is just multiplication by $k$. I’m sure that pari has methods for getting the logarithm and exponential of the formal group of your curve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It has been very helpful. Let me clarify it here, to calculate 24kP I have to use logarithm and exponential of the formal group of your curve which is given by L and E. From PARI :
L= L=z-(6534/5)*z^5+(136890/7)*z^7 ;
E=z+(6534/5)*z^5 ;
And z(24P)=-x/y= 2*3 + 3^2 + 2*3^3 + 2*3^4 + 2*3^5 + O(3^7). 
So from here, I substitute z(24P) into my L function, multiply by k, and then substitute into E to get the local parameter of z(24kP)? Is that true?

Comment: Sounds exactly right. Unfortunately, I no longer have the formula for the logarithm in front of me, and equally unfortunately I never got around to checking your value for $[24](P)$. But, believing your data, I agree with what you have written above. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much. I got my calculation right this time. Thank you again for your help explaining it to me.